# How to get screen name instead of user ID with tweepy

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

I'm printing out the tweets from my twitter feed to a CSV and want to get the CSV to show the username instead of the user ID.

My code uses tweepy.

```
outtweets.append([tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")])
```

This is what I use in my loop to get the user ID.
How would I go about to get the screen name instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets Tweet object and https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users User object.

This will reveal that you need to use:

```
tweet.user.name
```

to access the user name