# How to get authenticated user's screen name with Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to print `'Hello, {screen_name}'` but I am not sure how I can get this screen name using tweepy's functions. I am aware of the `api.me()` function, but I do not know how to only print the `screen_name` of all returned values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get screen name instead of user ID with tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853003/how-to-get-screen-name-instead-of-user-id-with-tweepy)

Comment: @dspencer no, I am looking for how to get the authenticated username (name of the user signed in w/ the access tokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After authenticating to the Twitter API, you may use the `me` API call to retrieve a `User` object. The `screen_name` of the authenticated user can be obtained by accessing the `screen_name` of this object, i.e.:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.me().screen_name
```

Since I couldn't find this documented in the tweepy documentation, I checked the [source](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py). The fields returned in the JSON response to the API call are set as attributes on the `User` class, making them accessible in this manner.